# Theano calling function without updating shared variables

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

In Theano, is it possible to call a function so that it doesn't automatically update the shared variables that you specified before compiling the computational graph?

For example, I have the following function to train a RNN:

```
train = theano.function(
    inputs=[x, h0, t],
    outputs=[loss, p],
    updates=updates  # updates the parameters using GD
)
```

However, when I only want to sample from the model (instead of training it), I would like to call the same function, but without automatically updating the parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just compile another function without the updates?

Comment: Of course, this is what I currently do. I was just wondering if it can be accomplished without another function.